# Excel VBA Redim Preserve Out of range

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to redim and preserve my array but it keeps coming up with an error that says it is out of range i do not know why?

```
Dim FirstArray(0) As Variant
Dim SecondArray(0) As Variant
Dim ArrSize As Variant

row = 9
ArrSize = 1

Do While Not Cells(row, 3).Comment Is Nothing
    FirstArray(ArrSize - 1) = Cells(row, 3).Value
    ReDim Preserve FirstArray(ArrSize)
    ArrSize = ArrSize + 1
    row = row + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
Dim FirstArray() as Variant
Dim SecondArray() As Variant
```

I made the same mistake initially

To declare a variable array, you don't give it an initial size.

Also, make sure you ReDim it to 1 before you assign its 0 index a value.

```
ReDim Preserve FirstArray(ArrSize)
FirstArray(ArrSize - 1) = Cells(row, 3).Value
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an ArrayList object which saves having to ReDim things. Also has added functionality ([see here for example](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=167349))

```
Dim FirstArray As Object

Set FirstArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
row = 9

Do While Not Cells(row, 3).Comment Is Nothing
    FirstArray.Add Cells(row, 3).Value
    row = row + 1
Loop
```